# Custom javascript callback in Bokeh to select column from dataframe and update plot

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I have an excel sheet that contains the concentrations of over 20 elements (each element is a column) over time (Runs).

I have to plot the concentrations vs time over the mean and standard deviations for each element.

I'd like to make a bokeh program that lets me select which element I want to view and updates the plot accordingly. I don't want to have to connect to the server in order for it to work, I want it to be a stand alone html. So, I understand I need to write a custom js callback to do this.

The way my code works right now is that I have a function that calculates the means and standard deviations, stores this in a new df and uses that df to make the plot.

Here's the code I have so far. Right now its coded in a way so that it only displays one element

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool,CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import Select
from bokeh.layouts import row, column

def get_data(low,element):
    mean=low[element].mean()
    plus_three_sigma=mean+(low[element].std()*3)
    minus_three_sigma=mean-(low[element].std()*3)
    plus_two_sigma=mean+(low[element].std()*2)
    minus_two_sigma=mean-(low[element].std()*2)
    df=pd.DataFrame({"Run":low["run"],element:low[element],"mean":mean,"plus_three_sigma":plus_three_sigma,"minus_three_sigma":minus_three_sigma,"plus_two_sigma":plus_two_sigma,"minus_two_sigma":minus_two_sigma})
    return df
def make_plot(df):
    tips=[("Run", "@Run"),("Concentration", "$y")]
    source=ColumnDataSource(df)
    p = figure(plot_width=1300, plot_height=800, x_range=df["Run"], tooltips=tips, title="QC Low", x_axis_label="Run ID",y_axis_label="Concentration ng/mL")
    p.line(x="Run", y="mean", line_width=1, color="black", source=source)
    p.line(x="Run", y="plus_three_sigma", line_width=1, color="red", source=source)
    p.line(x="Run", y="minus_three_sigma", line_width=1, color="red", source=source)
    p.line(x="Run", y="minus_two_sigma", line_width=1, color="green",line_dash="dashed",source=source)
    p.line(x="Run", y="plus_two_sigma", line_width=1, color="green",line_dash="dashed",source=source)
    pc=p.circle(x='Run', y="9Be",source=source)
    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
    return p

#callback = CustomJS(args=, code="""
#
#    }
#    source.change.emit();
#""")
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

os.chdir(r'')


low=pd.read_excel(r"", sheet_name="QC LOW", skiprows=5, usecols=range(0,34))
low["run"]=low["run"].astype(str)
low.loc[~(low["run"].str.contains("A")) & ~(low["run"].str.contains("B")),"run"]=pd.to_datetime(low.loc[(~low["run"].str.contains("A")) & (~low["run"].str.contains("B")),"run"]).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
cols=low.columns.tolist()
cols=cols[2:]

select = Select(title="Option:", value="9Be", options=cols)

output_file("output.html")

df=get_data(low,"9Be")
p=make_plot(df)
#select.js_on_change('value', callback)

show(row(select,p))
```

I don't understand how to write the javascript callback to update both the data and the plot. Do I need to move get_data into the java script callback? Should I not make the figure in a function? How would I write the javascript to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 2):

So there's a couple of things that need to change, and theres more than one way to do this, but this is how I've always gotten it to work.

1) Your df should be a dict grouped by in your case different elements. Something like this:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Element', sort = False).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict(orient = 'list'))
```

2) Your `columndatasource` will point to only the first key in that dict.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data = df2[0])
```

3) Your select values should be the keys of df2 (in other words, each element)

```
opts = [*df2.keys()]
select = Select(value = opts[0], options = opts)
```

4) Your JS will look like this:

```
callback = CustomJS(args = dict(graph=source, source= df2.to_dict()), code =
            """                
            graph.data = source[cb_obj.value];
            graph.change.emit();
            """)
```

graph is your columndatasource, and graph.data is your first elements **data**. Your `cb_obj.value` will be the option you select with the select and will act as the key to source (`df2.to_dict`) to pull the correctly selected data. In otherwords, when you select an element in your Select pull down, you will be swapping out the data with the newly selected element.

Finally getting it to display:

```
select.js_on_change('value', callback)
layout = column(select, p)
show(layout)
```

Comment: This is really helpful thanks. I'm still a little unsure where I would calculate the means and such. It needs to be re-calculated for each element so those would have to be updated as well